# UI base config for spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have a centralized configuration for spring boot service. I followed this [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/) to make it.

I have configServer and configs two separate project. Configs have several properties files. And configServer reading it and rendering to other services.

Now I want to make configs UI based.
e.g.
application.properties of configs which is hosted at git.

```
logging.path=logs
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security=INFO
```

It`s UI should be 
logging.path as key text box for value( logs ).

Is there any example for it. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: You can use consul as your configuration manager. It has very good in-built UI also which can serve the purpose for you.

Answer (score -1):

Since you mention using text box in your post, I'm assuming that by UI you mean GUI.

While I'm not aware of any examples (and you do not specify whether you want to have a destktop or web application) if you're using git to store configuration, your app needs to:

1. Checkout the git repo with configuration (using [JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) for example)
2. Load properties files generate edit window for each file (something
   similar to what IntelliJ does for environment variables in run
   configurations perhaps)
3. Save edits to files
4. Commit and push changes (again using [JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) or a similar library)